# Jquery Cookies Error

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have this bit of code where I try to set a cookie using jQuery before redirecting to another page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#offers-categories").click(function () {
      $.cookie("cardType", "1");
      window.location = "categories.html";
   });

});
```

This is the error that I get in the Console when I click the `#offers-categories` div:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new st.fn.init(e,t,X)} has no method 'cookie'
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034190/cookie-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)? There is no cookie method in standard jQuery.