# cookie is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Cookie plugin is included and all is working fine on first click, but when i try to click on another link with different data-id i have this error $.cookie is not a function, like that cookie can not be updated with new value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#row').live('click',function(){
        var msg_id = $(this).data('id');    
        $('#table_2').html('Loading...');
        $.cookie("chat_", msg_id, { expires: 1 });
        $('#table_2').load('http://google.com/mail_ajax.php?id='+msg_id,function(){
            $("#table_2").html();        

        });
    }); 

var chat_d = $.cookie('chat_');
var timeout = setInterval(reloadChat, 3000);    
function reloadChat () {
     $('#table_2').load('http://google.com/mail2ajax.php?id='+chat_d);
}
});
```

why i can't update cookie on 2nd click, and where can be problem ?

Comment: have you included the jquery cookie plugin?

Comment: `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>`

Comment: can you try `$.cookie` in the console? also `jQuery.cookie`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024539/jquery-cookie-is-not-a-function might give you some help.

Comment: which version of jquery are you using cause `.live` is deprecated as of 1.7!! if you're using later version use `.on`

Comment: You have probably re-included jQuery at some point after the cookie plugin was defined, causing jQuery to be redefined and any extensions that had been added to be wiped out. Perhaps the response that you're injecting into the DOM contains a script tag that points to jQuery. That would explain it working once, then failing.