# Jquery expand and collapse menu is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, menuitem

I am working on a sidebar menu navigation which expands and collapses when user clicks on the menu. On top of that, I want the menu to stay expanded if the link on the sub menu is active when the page loads.

This is the code sample that I am working on right now. Can someone please help me check the issue on my code?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  {
    var m = e("ul.menu li.sidebar ul.sub-menu");
    e("li")
  }
  e("ul.menu > li.sidebar > a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
    }),
    e(document).mouseup(function(i) {
      var n = e("li.sidebar");
      n.is(i.target) || 0 !== n.has(i.target).length || m.hide("fast")
    });
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.sidebar a {
  background-color: #122842;
  padding: 3%;
  color: white !important;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-submenu a {
  color: #6e6e6e !important;
  background-color: #e1ecf1 !important;
  display: block;
}
.sidebar .current-menu-item a {
  color: #22374f !important
}
.sidebar .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
.current-menu-ancestor .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu ">
  <li class="sidebar current-menu-ancestor"><a href="#">Menu A ▶</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="sidebar-submenu current-menu-item"><a href="a.com/menu1/">submenu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sidebar-submenu current-menu-item"><a href="a.com/menu1/#sectionb">submenu 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sidebar-submenu"><a href="a.com/menu2">submenu 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sidebar current-menu-ancestor"><a href="#">Menu B ▶</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="sidebar-submenu current-menu-item"><a href="a.com/menu1/#sectionc">submenu 4</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sidebar-submenu"><a href="a.com/menu2/#sectionb">submenu 5</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sidebar-submenu"><a href="a.com/menu3">submenu 6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sidebar"><a href="#">Menu C ▶</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="sidebar-submenu"><a href="a.com/menu4">submenu 7</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sidebar-submenu"><a href="a.com/menu5">submenu 8</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

These are the behavior that I want to achieve:

- Submenu 1, submenu 2, and submenu 4 are on the same page but different 'menu'. If the page is selected, both menu A and menu B expand while menu C stay collapse.
- If user clicks on submenu 3 which is under menu A, when the page loads, menu A expands while menu B and C collapse.
- Whenever a submenu is active, class "current-menu-item" is added to
  the li tag and class "current-menu-ancestor" is added to the ul tag

The issue that I have right now:

- The menu is automatically expanded when any sub-menu is active, but the menu is not clickable
- when I replace the jQuery with the code below, the menu is clickable
  and automatically expanded when any sub-menu is active, BUT the sub
  menu is not clickable (not opening the link)

  ```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
   jQuery('.sidebar a').click(function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();
   if (jQuery(('.sidebar').children('.sub-menu:first').is(':visible')) {
             jQuery(('.sidebar').children('.sub-menu:first').hide();
        } else {
             jQuery(('.sidebar').children('.sub-menu:first').show();
        }
  ```

  });
  });

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please add jquery cookies library in your head just after jquery

```
<script src="path/to/Scripts/jquery_cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

check this for more info [stack-cookie-is-not-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024539/jquery-cookie-is-not-a-function)