# $.cookie is not a function console error

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-plugins

I keep getting this error "**$.cookie is not a function**" when trying to implement jQuery cookies.

As far as I can tell I'm implementing the plugin correctly:

**First loading**: 
/wp-content/themes/divi-child/js.cookie.js

**Then loading my custom code:**
/wp-content/themes/divi-child/custom.js

But using the following in 'custom.js':

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.cookie("test", 1);
});
```

**...creates this error in console:**

custom.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
    at HTMLDocument. (custom.js:2)

Site can be previewed here:
http://dtodd.co.uk/

Comment: You are not loading a jQuery cookie library but instead [js.cookie.js](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) twice. It is using the syntax `Cookies.set('name', 'value');`- I vote to close as off topic: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: Additionally it is a duplicate of the easily found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024539/jquery-cookie-is-not-a-function - please search for your title in google before asking next time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery $.cookie is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024539/jquery-cookie-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

`$.cookie` is not a standard jQuery function and the plugin needs to be downloaded here. Make sure to include the appropriate  tag where necessary. Can be downloaded from: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

When including the cookie script, make sure to include jQuery ***FIRST***, then the cookie plugin.

Comment: Should be closed as non-repo/typo

Comment: @mplungjan Uhm until and unless we dont tell OP, how will he learn ? closing the question is OK, but give him some time to reply

Comment: It is already answered in the comment. Closing does not delete the question. It is not useful for anyone but him - and I could likely have hammer closed with a duplicate

Comment: @mplungjan you need patience mate !

Comment: For what? With a minimum of research (typing the title of his question into google) he could have saved everybody time - I have loads of patience with people who have a real problem :)

Answer (score 0):

entirely probably that WP has the new version of the cookie.js included, and downloaded from here:

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

and the answer can be seen in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38492574/1470145