# jQuery plugin with setInterval and anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I need get value from cookies with jQuery.

Everything works fine until i try get value with setInterval() function: "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.cookie is not a function".

Why jQuery not recognize plugin (in my case jQuery.cookie) in function called with setInterval()?

```
var view = jQuery.cookie('test_view'); //ok

var modal = function(){
    openPage('after2min');
};

setTimeout(modal, 5000);

function openPage()
{
    var view = jQuery.cookie('test_view'); //error - Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.cookie is not a function
}
```

Comment: This could happen if you are loading jQuery.js again after the initial page load. It would overwrite original jQuery object and any plugins. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024539/jquery-cookie-is-not-a-function#18065072) possible reasons for error "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.cookie is not a function"

Comment: @charlietfl I have jQuery only in one place.

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan Cookie plugin exists.

Comment: Is there any ajax that might be loading another copy?

Comment: @charlietfl, yes, ajax exists. So maybe i can copy jQuery object and use it? var object = jQuery; object.cookie() - no't working,

Comment: Not if you load jquery again after the plugin was loaded. The plugin is registered to first version which gets wiped out