# setting cookies using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, cookies, path

I used the code provided by SpYk3HH on the page: "[$.cookie is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034190/cookie-is-not-a-function#new-answer)" to set cookies for storing background images.

But the cookie i set is being set separately for home page from other pages specifically because of difference in path of cookies.

The paths being set are : `path=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en` for home page and `"path=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/"` for all other pages. I am `unable to set the path to path=/` using the js provided by SpYk3HH. It seems it does not have provision for setting path. 
 see code for setting cookie: 
    $.setCookie("backgroundImage", imageFile,);
Please help or suggest a work around.

Also, when I try to use jquery.cookie.js instead of the js provide by SpYk3HH, i get an error $.cookie is not a function. I already tried changing the file name to jquery_cookie.js and also made sure that jquery is not being loaded more than once. Other option is to enable Mod_sec but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js

Then just set your cookie like this:
$.cookie(cookieName,cookieValue,{expires: 7, path: '/'});

Comment: I already tried this. Give error $.cookie is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure jquery.cookie.js is being loaded after jQuery?
And that your script for $.cookie [...] is being executed after the plugin is loaded?

Looks like a script positioning problem!