# Check cookie and addClass, but it is to slow

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

On window load function I check if there is a cookie and I add a css class to hide an element. But it is not fast enough, when open the site it shows the hidden element for a second. Any better way to do that without seeing the hidden element?

This is the script I am using (I use jQuery):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    if ($.cookie('note')) {
        $('.note').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hide it first then only show it if the cookie **doesn't** exist.

Comment: Have you tried using document ready as opposed to window load?

Comment: FYI [load() is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643160/load-method-deprecated) and should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply invert the function to only show the image if the cookie doesn't exist:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    if (typeof $.cookie('note') === 'undefined') {
        $('.note').removeClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Obviously your default state should include the `hide` class.

also, as mentioned don't use `load()` it's deprecated, doesn't work very well and add's an unnecessary delay to your code running.

Comment: I am trying this, but this does not work:
if (typeof $.cookie('note') === 'undefined'

Comment: What happens [when you debug it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: I get this: 116 Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4_0PpHmsIheWU5JZkRGT3RWNkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: But you were using $.cookie above o_O. This is a different question, [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034190/cookie-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Ok thanks! Is there a way doing it without the jQuery Cookie plugin?

Comment: Mmhh if I add the jQuery Cookie Plugin the error goes away, but the class hide won't be removed.